# Is there a way to adjust the size of content in a Kivy popup

Tags: python, kivy, popup

I have made a popup in Kivy, but I'm not sure how to edit the size of the content and label. When I shrink the window down, the content extends off the side of the popup; I want the content (and label) to dynamically shrink as I shrink the window.

[Picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z7kW.png)

How might I go about doing this? Here's the code for my popup:

```
def invalidtop1():
toppop1 = Popup(title = 'Invalid Input', size_hint=(.8, .4), content = Label(text = 'Must have J = |j1 - j2|, |j1 - j2| + 1, ..., j1 + j2.'))

toppop1.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first cut, you can make the `text_size` of the `Label` follow the `size` of the `Label`. That will force the `text` of the `Label` to be drawn within the `Label`. You can define a custom `Label`:

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass
```

Then define a `kv` rule for that new class:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel>:
    text_size: self.size
''')
```

The above accomplishes binding the `text_size` to the `size` of `MyLabel`. Then use `MyLabel` in place of `Label` in your `Popup`:

```
toppop1 = Popup(title = 'Invalid Input', size_hint=(.8, .4), content = MyLabel(text = 'Must have J = |j1 - j2|, |j1 - j2| + 1, ..., j1 + j2.'))
```

You might want to add `halign='center', valign='center'` to the `MyLabel` for a bit more pleasing look. This will only help to some extent. A more complex solution would be to calculate the font size needed to fit the text in the `Label`.